# Como convertir una FECHA MySql (Que esta insertada en una tabla) a un OBJETO en PHP

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de renderizar una fecha para convertirla en **OBJETO** pero no lo consigo en su lugar me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

string(19) "2022-11-16 22:37:48"
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: date_format(): Argument #1 ($object) must be of type DateTimeInterface, string given in

mi codigo es este:

```
 $sqlVerificarHora = "SELECT MAX(Fecha) AS Fecha FROM subirnes WHERE IDUsuario = '$_SESSION[ID]'";
    $resultadoHORA = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlVerificarHora);
    $hileraFECHA = mysqli_fetch_array($resultadoHORA, MYSQLI_ASSOC);


    $LaUltimaFECHA = $hileraFECHA['Fecha'] ;
    var_dump($LaUltimaFECHA);
    $fecha = date_format($LaUltimaFECHA,'Y-m-d H:i:s');

    var_dump($fecha);
    date_default_timezone_set("America/Mexico_City"); //En mi caso que estoy en mexico asigno la zona horaria
    (date("d"));

    function Pasaron24Horas($LaUltimaFECHA)
    {
        date_default_timezone_set("America/Mexico_City"); //En mi caso que estoy en mexico asigno la zona horaria
        $LaUltimaFECHA = date($LaUltimaFECHA); //Convierto el valor a foramato de fecha
        $Hoy = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");    //Tomo la fecha actual

        $Diferencia = $LaUltimaFECHA->diff($Hoy); //Ver cuanto tiempo ha pasado
        $DiferenciaHoras = $Diferencia->h;  //Convertirlo a horas

        if ($DiferenciaHoras > 24) {
            $Resultado = true;
        } else {
            $Resultado = false;
        }

        return $Resultado;
    }
```

Osea me marca el error en el **date_format**. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el string es `"2022-11-16 22:37:48"` no se entiende que quieras convertirla **al mismo string** intentándo hacer esto usando [date_format()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.format.php):

```
$fecha = date_format($LaUltimaFECHA,'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Si lo que quieres es crear un objeto [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.construct.php) hazlo así:

```
$fecha = new DateTime($LaUltimaFECHA);
```

Y te devolverá un objeto parecido a esto (el timezone cambia según el huso horario del dispositivo que lo crea, pero puedes forzarlo mirando la documentación sobre ello en el link anterior):

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2022-11-16 22:37:48.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
)
```

Comment: saludos de nuevo (Pondre en practica lo que me dices). Solo por mencionar algo lo que pasa es que me marca error porque me dice la consola:

**"Expected type object found string"** a la variable **$LaUltimaFECHA**->diff($Hoy) 

Como que el IDE me detecta que no puede hacerle eso ultimo de **->diff($Hoy)** Porque lo detecta como string y no como objeto.

(De todos modos pongo en practica lo que me dices, ni si quiera se que significa estas FLECHAS -> => (Gracias) )

Comment: Si te dedicas tan solo a copiar y pegar código y esperar que mágicamente funcione te encontrarás con muchos problemas de este tipo (de hecho muchas de tus preguntas son por eso, por no leer o no entender la documentación).  Si te fijas en el **diff**, eso solo sirve si, tal como dice su [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.diff.php), ambos son objetos DateTime: `Devuelve la diferencia entre dos objetos DateTime`. Por lo tanto, para solucionar ese diff haz esto: `$LaUltimaFECHA = new DateTime($LaUltimaFECHA); ` y `$Hoy = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));`

Comment: Y las flechas de este tipo `->` indican que en el lado izquierdo de la flecha tienes un objeto, y en el lado derecho tienes o bien una propiedad del objeto o bien un método del objeto (un método no es más que una función definida en la clase del objeto, es decir, propia del objeto solamente)

Comment: no copio y pego si lo razono (Tengo que) pero (Como me imagino sabes) es tanta la documentación que es fácil perderse. Sobre lo de las flechas te agradezco mucho la respuesta porque como que ya me aclaro más... Es que el punto no es leer la documentación sino interpretarlo en tu cabeza. En efecto esa flecha la traduzco algo así como un **"Dentro DE su... "esta" propiedad**. Pero ya me lo desglosaste y me ayudo bastante (Lo otro parece estar funcionando ya gual, muchas gracias masterguru)

Comment: La otra flecha escrita así `=>` normalmente se usa más en arrays e indica que a su lado izquierdo hay una clave y a su lado derecho su valor, el cual puede ser un string (eso es fácil de entender) o bien un objeto o un array (lo cual complica su lectura pues puedes encontrarte cosas así:  `"clave=>["clave2 dentro del valor de clave"=>["clave3 dentro del valor de clave2"=>"valor clave 3"],["clave4 dentro del valor de clave2"=>"valor clave 4"]]` lo cual reconozco que es jodido de entender, je, pero para eso esta el `print_r()` y el `var_dump()` que ayudan a ver su estructura real

Comment: y por último, los corchetes `[ ]` indican que es un array() (es la forma abreviada de escribir cosas asi:  `array('clave'=>'valor')` pues se pueden escribir asi: `['clave'=>'valor']`